# What does "build artifact" mean in the context of a dockerized development environment?

Tags: docker, build, developer-tools

In a [blog post](https://medium.com/on-docker/development-environments-with-docker-89657c7b4ea2#.6234qc9nf) about creating a dockerized development environment there is a section where the following question and first paragraph answer are given:

> #### What type of build artifacts do you want?
>
> The build artifact I wanted in this example was a running container.
>   Either Compose or docker would have been appropriate tools to that
>   end. In your scenario you might prefer to have a distributable image,
>   or you might prefer that the build produce a binary on your host
>   operating system.

I read in [another question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/106473/245542) that an *artifact* can be anything created during a process. From reading through other answers it seems like the context in which the term is used is important.

In the context of using [Docker](https://github.com/docker/docker) to create a development environment, what does *build artifact* mean?

Answer (score 25):

### **In short** I'd say: `Environment + Compiled output = Artifact`.

That is, the *full environment including all tools, dependencies etc. needed to build the source (**image**), + the actually built/compiled result (**runnables/libs**)*, with the latter stored inside the former!

This way, in case of a crash/bug, everything is there for you, ready to be debugged no matter what dusty & old version of your software the issue occurred on. *

<sub>*: I didn't include source in above description, but that could also be preferable. Otherwise, since we all use version control, it can be mounted afterwards if necessary.</sub>

### **Artifact vs Image:**

*(note from comments)*

"Artifact" is merely a word for something that is produced; in this context a byproduct when developing software. So the runnables/libs are the artifact(s) produced when compiling source, and the image is the artifact produced by the whole "build"-step, basically *an artifact containing one or more other artifact(s)!*

This makes more sense when you start working with automated build, test & deployment pipelines (AKA [Continuous Delivery](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/ContinuousDelivery.html)).

---

**Note 1:**

This would be the end-result, thus how you choose to setup any steps up until this point is up to you ([split-image approach](https://www.google.se/search?q=docker%20split-image&ie=&oe=#spf=1) etc.).

**Note 2:**

I've just recently started playing with docker in combination with continuous delivery, so these are just my initial two cents :)

Comment: Thank you for the two cents :) What is the difference between an artifact and an image then? Your definition sounds alot like an image to me.

Comment: In this case, the image _is_ the artifact! :) "Artifact" is merely a word for something that is produced, in this context a byproduct when developing software. So the runnables/libs are the artifact(s) produced when compiling source, and the **image** is the artifact produced by the whole "build"-step, basically an artifact containing one or more other artifact(s)! 
This makes more sense when you start working with automated build, test & deployment pipelines. AKA [Continuous Delivery](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/ContinuousDelivery.html).

Comment: @helmesjo I'd add that example in your comment to your answer, it made it a lot more clear to me :)

Comment: @guival Sure! Updated the answer. Let me know if it became more (or less) confusing... :)

Answer (score 6):

In terms of build pipelines in general the Artifact is the software component that is produced during the build, stored in a repository and ultimately deployed into your different environments.

For non-dockerized Java applications this is typically a JAR/WAR.
For dockerized applications this is typically an image that contains the JAR/WAR.